# if jquery has no 'readonly' on 'select' and 'checkbox'?

Tags: jquery

I can't find any function like readonly on 'select' and 'checkbox'. 'Disable 'seems to be an option but the variable will be no longer exist. I just fix them out by:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
        if ( $( this ).prop( "checked" ) ){
            $(this).change(function() {
                $(this).prop('checked', true);
            });

        } else{
            $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        }

    });

$('select option:not(:selected)').prop("disabled", true);
```

They seems OK and may leave only one choice that I want and others will be disabled.

Are there any other options?

Comment: only disable for select and checkbox

Answer (score 0):

There is only `disabled` for checkboxes and selects. This is because `readonly` prevents the user from changing the value of the input and not from interacting and changing the state of the input.

With checkboxes and select input you change the state instead of the value and so readonly has no effect.

So you should use `disable` instead.
To still submit your values you can use a hidden field that contains the value you want to submit and only display the `disabled` checkbox to the user to let him know it is there.